# Display or hide elements on window resize using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm a bigger in jQuery and trying to build a hamburger menu when the window is smaller than 750px and it works how it suppose to. The problem is that when I resize the window to be more than 750px the hamburger doesn't change back to a regular menu. I tried $(window).resize but it doesn't do what I want it to.

My jQuery Code
$(document).ready(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();

```
if (width <= 750) {        
    //Variables
    var ham = $('.hamburger');
    var nav = $('nav')

    //Hamburger Function
    ham.show();
    ham.click(function() {
        $('.menu').toggle();
    });

    //Navigation Menu Function
    nav.hide();      

} else {
    $('p').append('Bigger than 750');
}
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinBurciaga/0vn00oLh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(window).resize should be the correct function but you also need to call the function to check initially to ensure the menu is shown correctly

```
//initialize the hamburger menu once on ready
$(document).ready(function() {
     var ham = $('.hamburger');

    //Hamburger Function
    ham.show();
    ham.click(function() {
        $('.menu').toggle();
    }); 

    //call the checkWindowWith by yourself on ready
    checkWindowWidth();
});

//register the resize function
$(window).resize(checkWindowWidth);

function checkWindowWidth() {
    var width = $(window).width();

    if (width <= 750) { 
        $('.hamburger').show();
        $('.nav').hide();          
    } else {
        $('.hamburger').hide();
        $('nav').show();
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0vn00oLh/1/)